# Access Server 2008R2 RemoteApp with MS iOS RDP App without RD Web Access

Tags: remote-desktop-services, ios, remoteapp

Is it possible to connect to a Server 2008 R2 RemoteApp using the iOS Microsoft Remote Desktop App v8.0.9, across LAN and VPN, with only the RD Session Host service installed?  That is, without RD Web Access, RD Gateway and RD Connection Broker?  The same way we can by giving a user an .rdp file?
I don't see any place in the client to put the RemoteApp parameters into the iOS app.